# javascript adding items to json object using a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested-for-loop, nested-json

so i have one array with names, and one with other json-data i can access using a method.
I was trying to do

```
let out = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        let feed = {names[j] : getData(data[i])};
        out.push(feed);
    }
}
```

So the expected output would be an array a bit like this:
`[{"jonas": {"a" : 1, "b": 2}}, {"lara" : {"a": 73, "b": 0}}, "jakob": {"a" : null, "b": "something"}]`

What actually happened was an error occuring:
*unecpected token '['*
ment was the '[' at ...let feed = {names[ /*←this here*/ j]...

Comment: Use a square bracket around names[j], eg. ` let feed = {[names[j]] : getData(data[i])};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a variable as a key to an object you need to enclose it in [], try using this `let feed = {[names[j]] : getData(data[i])};`